Jodit XHTML mode - or close void tags
Is there an XHTML mode for Jodit?  Or a way to have void tags like <br>, <hr>, <img> closed by the editor.  I'm finding that Jodit is overriding those closed void tags with their "open" HTML equivalents even when I close them before populating the editor.
